# CQL and range on secondary indexed columns

Tags: cassandra, cql

The below CQL query resulted in an error saying

> No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with equals operator

Note that the column `age` was already secondary indexed.

```sql
select * from employee where age > 25
```

However I had another secondary indexed column `type`. So when I used that...

```sql
select * from employee where type='engineer' and age > 25
```

I seemed to get proper results.

How does this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cassandra's built-in secondary indexes are more of a hash-style index, as opposed to a B-tree.

As such, **at least one equality comparison is required** to perform lookups efficiently (any additional column predicates result in late-filtering of the equality matches).

Try the following wiki page for a decent starting point for questions about Cassandra's secondary indexes: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/SecondaryIndexes